# Ansible Rolling Deployment across Multiple Load Balancers

Tags: ansible

For our production environment, we have load balancers in each region, with multiple webservers behind each of them. We'd like to do a rolling deployment using Ansible across the whole environment, but with the requirement that we don't take down too many servers at a time in each region. Here's an example of our inventory:

```
[webservers]
server1.europe.ourdeployment.com
server2.europe.ourdeployment.com
server1.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server2.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server3.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server4.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server5.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server6.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server7.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server8.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
```

And our deploy command:

```
- hosts: webservers
  serial: 3
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/deploy-application.yml
```

If we run it like this, it's going to take out all the servers in Europe for the first batch, so we'd have downtime. I know we could reorder the inventory file to make sure the batches work out, but that seems brittle. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Even if it looks like overkill, the best way would be to divide webservers in groups ( rearrange inventory ):

Example Hosts File:

```
[webservers:children]
euwebservers
uswebservers


[euwebservers]
server1.europe.ourdeployment.com
server2.europe.ourdeployment.com

[uswebservers]
server1.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server2.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server3.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server4.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server5.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server6.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server7.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
server8.northamerica.ourdeployment.com
```

Playbook:

```
# my_playbook.yml
---
- hosts: euwebservers
  serial: 30%

  tasks:

    - include: tasks/deploy-application.yml

- hosts: uswebservers
  serial: 30%

  tasks:

    - include: tasks/deploy-application.yml

- hosts: webservers

  tasks:

    - name: Do something on all webservers
      template: src=foo dest=bar
```

You can always address all servers using `webservers` group or individaul regions based on subgroup name.

Another option would be to stay with the original playbook but limit execution to particular group of servers:

```
# my_playbook.yml
---
- hosts: webservers
  serial: 30%

  tasks:

    - include: tasks/deploy-application.yml
```

And run `ansible-playbook` as follows:

`ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml --limit=euwebservers`